# Do not show column to user

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, site-column

We have a library where when user uploads file, inputs metadata in 4 custom fields via Nintex forms

We also have 2 other fields which holds year & month (we enter a default value) Users are not supposed to touch this and will not have visibility as they enter their data using Nintex forums (on 4 custom fields only)

Now some users have gotten smart and used the SharePoint's own 'Details' menu to see the metadata and started to adjust the month/year as well.

Is there anyway to avoid this issue at all? Such as hiding these columns? Workaround?

*I've looked around internet and solutions offered were related to much older SP and not for Online.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean they are using the "details" menu ?

are you not hiding the columns from the views? if this is the case then you have to remove the public views with the private fields and only let the people with the right sets of permissions to create private views with those fields

are they accessing the data using the DispForm.aspx view ? 
if that's the case, then you have to hide the columns enabling managed content types and making those fields hidden

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention detail SharePoint version, while you could hide html element by inserting CSS to content editor/script editor web part usually, as users won't touch 'Details'( DispForm.aspx) form for business processing as per your description.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill out another list in Nintex (Forms) that don't have the fields that you don't want the users to edit. And then you can make a Nintex workflow that copies the items from the one list to the other, where the users don't have write access to but has the extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by disabling 'Quick Edit' for the library. This way they cannot edit the metadata except for using Nintex forms. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint designer you can specify the rules for specific columns and you can make it so that regular users cannot mess with views or columns